# nesting of ng-view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to have two angular apps to one page.

my scenario: i having a website which is having lot of apps. so for eg header, footer, left sidebar, right sidebar will not change for the whole webpage, only the content will change. so i used angular templating(ng-view). while clicking on the app like calendar, it will be loaded in the ng-view. in the calendar app i have a ng-view for different views(month,week,day)
so it will be like

```
<ng-view>
    calendar or some other app
    <ng-view>
        month or week or day or SOMEOTHER APP TEMPLATE
    </ng-view>
</ng-view>
```

when i tried this the browser is crashed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Cant you use ng-include to do nesting?

Comment: @smk ng-include is different it will simply include the contents from a file, why should i get the data from the server when the user doesn't request that content?

Comment: As @smk pointed out you can achieve the same using ng-include as there can only be one ng-view per page. What is the problem using ng-include, i did not get your concern. Template loading for ng-view and ng-include are similar.

Comment: @Chandermani if i am using ng-include while loading the calendar i will be having all three views(month,week,day). what i want is when the user clicks on week or day it has to load that week template from the server, not at first.

Comment: one solution is use route to determine template for ng-view. Numerous ways to achive what you want. Study available demos and tutorials to get better understanding of how to work with angular

Comment: @charlietfl we can use routes that i know but here i am having two ng-views if i write two routes file it will be a conflict

Comment: This is a fine question, OP may be misleaded to somewhere else but nothing is wrong with the question itself, why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngView` is coupled with `$routeProvider`, which means that it is updated according to the current route/uri. Which also means you cannot bind two different views to a single URI.

You can just use `ngInclude` with a url that you want to show. It works same as `ngView` in terms of fetching from server.

You would not download all of the 3 urls at once if you just provide the url, it would be fetched *on demand*.

However, in most of the applications, it is better to serve all the possible static files at once and then cache it, which would result in overall better performance; only the initial load would suffer a bit; which is better than a slow application in general.

I would prefer to wait 2 more seconds if that would make the whole application respond faster.